# SELECT item, date WHERE date < sysdate - 60

Tags: sql, oracle

Here's my sql script. I'm trying to pull all items that haven't been invoiced in 60 days. It's only returning one line. Any idea why? Thanks for your help!

```
SELECT oel.ordered_item Part_No,
       MAX(rca.trx_date) AS "Last Invoice Date"
FROM    oe_order_lines_all oel,
        ra_customer_trx_all rca
WHERE rca.trx_date < trunc(sysdate)-60
GROUP BY oel.ordered_item
```

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, modern `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: What @GordonLinoff said and where is your join condition?

Comment: missing the inner join condition between rca and oel

Comment: You are creating a cartesian product in your query. Create a JOIN first.

Comment: By all items, do you mean all order lines which haven't been invoiced in the past 60 days? or all "ITEMS/Products" for which no order nor invoice exists in the past 60 days?

Comment: That is pretty odd. Is that the EXACT query you are using? Since it is a Cartesian join and it returns exactly one row, this means two things. There is exactly one transaction that hasn't been invoiced in 60 days, which perhaps is possible; and there is exactly one `ordered_item` in your `oe_order_lines_all` table, which is VERY, VERY WEIRD. I would rather believe that is NOT your actual query (and wonder why not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add condition for this line for ',', which is `inner join` here,

```
SELECT oel.ordered_item Part_No,
       MAX(rca.trx_date) AS "Last Invoice Date"
FROM    oe_order_lines_all oel,
        ra_customer_trx_all rca  
WHERE rca.trx_date < trunc(sysdate)-60 --------shoud be a condition connects rca and oel
GROUP BY oel.ordered_item
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why only one row is returned.  But you are missing join conditions.  This would be obvious if you used proper `JOIN` syntax.

Based on your description, the logic you want is more like this:

```
SELECT oel.ordered_item as Part_No,
       MAX(rca.trx_date) AS "Last Invoice Date"
FROM oe_order_lines_all oel LEFT JOIN
     ra_customer_trx_all rca
     ON oel.?? = rca.??
GROUP BY oel.ordered_item
HAVING MAX(rca.trx_date) < trunc(sysdate) - 60 OR MAX(rca.trx_date) IS NULL;
```

The `??` is for the columns used for joining the tables.